# Making a ActionScript 3 Menu,Loading and Unload

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, animate-cc

So, it's me again with my dumb AS3 questions.

So.

I managed loops, and (due to flash 16000 frames limit) i now have to load swf's

So i'm testing in 3 simples swf's (gonna attached them and the FLA's into a mega link)

I have:

- Menu.swf (main, with text saying "menu" and two buttons , one for 1.swf and other for 2.swf)
- 1.swf (text saying "1" and a button for menu.swf)
- 2.swf (text saying "2" and a button for menu.swf)

The problem is that when i click on the button 1, the text and buttons from the menu.swf is still showing. Is there anyway to clear it? should i put everything on top of a rectangle?

Any better ideas? thanks

https://mega.nz/#!TJ9FHDyb!gzirltUCMCFJ3_q26idRs17if1KCBE56WxkVnw7skXs

Comment: Attach the **Loader** instance to the **Stage** and hide the current content with **visible = false;** To understand display list hierarchy, read this: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html

Comment: I might use this in the future, right now i made a simple decision,

Made a big white rectangle, and before i load the new movie, i "jump" to said rectangle and then i load the movie, that way nothing gets overlayed!